# Laravel many to many relationship need to execute a query to get users list where role_id = 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

I have the below tables

1. **users**          :   id | name
2. **projects**       :   id | name
3. **user_project**   :   id | user_id | project_id

My Models contains

1. **User.php**

   public function projects()
   {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class);
   }
2. **Project.php**

   public function users() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
   }

In my controller file, I want to get a list of users using the User model whose role_id is 5.

Something like below

```
User::query()->roles(5);
```

*Help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you omitted something from your question as nothing about it makes a reference to a `role` model or table.

Comment: Why not make it from Role ? Like Role::find(5)->users ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)?

```
User::whereHas('roles', function($q){
    $q->where('id', 5);
})->get();
```

This will only return users whose `roles.id` column equals `5`.

Comment: Thanks Dan. You got my exact point and your suggestion works for me.